# Angular classnames error ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, classname

I have the following standard angular code and want to see the classes that are applied when an user

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="loginId">Login Id</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="loginId"
        [(ngModel)]="model.loginId"
        name="loginId"
        required
        #loginIdInput
      />
      className: {{ loginIdInput.className }}
    </div>
```

However I get the following error in the console

`ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: 'ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid'.`

Why is this happening, is this standard ?

Comment: is this the entire content of your component's template? it might also be worth including as much of your component class as possible.

I would also try commenting out everything in your component except for the parts that are necessary for the snippet you've posted to function, just to eliminate any external factors

Comment: This is literally all I have.  I'm just trying to see the classes applied when users navigate change (touched, pristine, changed, dirty).  Standard stuff I would say